# PowerShell to remove all letters and dashes leaving UPC

Tags: powershell, filenames

I have about 1,800 .pdfs including a UPC with dashes and text that need to be removed to manage. I found a code to remove extra spaces and underscores.

How do I remove all text leaving just the UPCs?

```
01182232110_V1R1_CartonOL_KP_DNV15.pdf
```

... to ...

```
01182232110.pdf
```

Comment: i would split on the `_` and then take the zero item from the results. [*grin*]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# Targets .pdf files in the current dir.
# Add a -LiteralPath / -Path argument to target a different dir.
# Add -Recurse to target .pdf files in the target dir's entire *subtree*.
Get-ChildItem -Filter *.pdf |
  Rename-Item -NewName {  $_.Name -replace '_.+(?=\.)' } -WhatIf
```

<sup>Note: The [`-WhatIf` common parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_commonparameters#whatif) in the command above *previews* the operation. Remove `-WhatIf`  once you're sure the operation will do what you want.</sup>

[`-replace`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators#replacement-operator)  `'_.+(?=\.)'` in essence removes all characters starting with the first `_` from the input file's base name (preserving the extension).